# Firefox Clicking the Top of Elements on Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am running Selenium 2.37 with Firefox 25, but I have been having this same issue for quite some time now with previous versions as well. On Chrome 31 and IE 10, all links seem to be clicked directly in the middle. On Firefox, it seems to always click the very top of the element, which can be a pain at times. It is not too hard to get around usually, but it can create inconsistencies at times when running cross-browser testing.

Is there any way to tell selenium to click in the middle of an element? I am using the basic IWebElement.Click(). In my particular instance, I sometimes have to put conditionals in tests based on the browser, which I would prefer not to do if possible.

Comment: I am curious what kind of links you are testing that would require specific cursor positioning

Comment: On certain links, I only identify up to the td, for example, so I don't identify the anchor, and the link will not be clicked on Firefox. The example which makes this most difficult, though, is one where I am dragging gadgets around. Because of Firefox's cursor positioning, gadgets will always be dragged to a different place than IE and Chrome.

Comment: So you have no way to actually reference the element using xpath or something?